# AMCL: cannot match well, jumps crazily

Tags: slam, localization, navigation, amcl, fake-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I load the map (built by hector slam before) by map_server and my scan is in rosbag. When I play rosbag. The scan is in "scan" frame while the map is in "map" frame. How to solve the problem?

I know that I also need odometry. But I dont understand how can this get a tf tree? AMCL only provide odom->map. Its not enough to get scan->map.

I want to use AMCL to localize in the given map.

------------------------------------ update ----------------------------------------

Now the tf tree is right. But scan jumps a lot in the map, causing AMCL not able to work. Anyone has idea?

Here is my code sending tf(odom->base_link) based on odometry data.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <tf/transform_broadcaster.h>
#include <nav_msgs/Odometry.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Pose.h>

void Posecallback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr & odom_msg)
{
    static tf::TransformBroadcaster br;
    tf::Transform odom2body;
    tf::Quaternion q(odom_msg->pose.pose.orientation.x,
                     odom_msg->pose.pose.orientation.y,
                     odom_msg->pose.pose.orientation.z,
                     odom_msg->pose.pose.orientation.w);

    odom2body.setOrigin(tf::Vector3(odom_msg->pose.pose.position.x,
                                    odom_msg->pose.pose.position.y,
                                    odom_msg->pose.pose.position.z));
//    q.setRPY(odom_msg->pose.pose.orientation.x,
//             odom_msg->pose.pose.orientation.y,
//             odom_msg->pose.pose.orientation.z,
//             odom_msg->pose.pose.orientation.w);
    odom2body.setRotation(q);
    br.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(odom2body,ros::Time::now(),"scanmatch_odom","base_link"));

}



int main(int argc, char ** argv )
{
    ros::init(argc,argv,"odom2base_TF");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Subscriber odom_sub=n.subscribe("scanmatch_odom",50,&Posecallback);
    ros::spin();
    return 0;
}
```

the launch file is like this:

```
<launch>
<!--include file="/home/wbw/catkin_ws/src/navigation/robot_pose_ekf/launch/test.launch"/-->

<node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="/home/wbw/mydata/mymap.yaml"/>

<node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl" output="screen">
  <!-- Publish scans from best pose at a max of 10 Hz -->
  <param name="odom_model_type" value="diff"/>
  <param name="odom_alpha5" value="0.1"/>
  <param name="transform_tolerance" value="0.2" />
  <param name="gui_publish_rate" value="10.0"/>
  <param name="laser_max_beams" value="100"/>
  <param name="min_particles" value="500"/>
  <param name="max_particles" value="5000"/>
  <param name="kld_err" value="0.05"/>
  <param name="kld_z" value="0.99"/>
  <param name="odom_alpha1" value="2"/>
  <param name="odom_alpha2" value="2"/>
  <param name="odom_alpha3" value="2"/>
  <param name="odom_alpha4" value="2"/>
  <param name="laser_z_hit" value="0.5"/>
  <param name="laser_z_short" value="0.05"/>
  <param name="laser_z_max" value="0.05"/>
  <param name="laser_z_rand" value="0.5"/>
  <param name="laser_sigma_hit" value="0.2"/>
  <param name="laser_lambda_short" value="0.1"/>
  <param name="laser_lambda_short" value="0.1"/>
  <param name="laser_model_type" value="likelihood_field"/>
  <param name="laser_likelihood_max_dist" value="2.0"/>
  <param name="update_min_d" value="0.2"/>
  <param name="update_min_a" value="0.5"/>
  <param name="resample_interval" value="0.5"/>
  <param name="transform_tolerance" value="0.1"/>
  <param name="recovery_alpha_slow" value="0.0"/>
  <param name="recovery_alpha_fast" value="0.0"/>
    <param name="odom_frame_id" value="scanmatch_odom"/>
    <param name="use_map_topic" value="true"/>
    <param name="initial_cov_xx" value="5.0*5.0"/>
    <param name="initial_cov_yy" value="5.0*5.0"/>
    <param name="initial_pose_x" value="0.0"/>
    <param name="initial_pose_y" value="0.0"/>

</node>

<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_laser"  
        args="0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 /base_link /velodyne 50">                                                
</node>

<!--node pkg="odom2base" type="odom2base_node" name="odom2base" output="screen"/-->

 <node pkg="laser_scan_matcher" type="laser_scan_matcher_node" name="laser_scan_matcher_node" output="screen">
    <remap from="odom" to="scanmatch_odom"/>
        <param name="fixed_frame" value = "scanmatch_odom"/>
        <param name="base_frame" value = "base_link"/>
        <param name="use_cloud_input" value="false"/>
        <param name="publish_tf" value="true"/>
        <param name="publish_odom" value="true"/>
        <param name="use_odom" value="false"/>
        <param name="use_imu" value="false"/>
        <param name="use_alpha_beta" value="true"/>
        <param name="max_iterations" value="10"/>
    </node>


<param name="/use_sim_time" value="true"/>
  <node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="play" 
    args="/home/wbw/mydata/odomscan.bag --clock">
    
  </node>

</launch>
```

The dismatch is like this...

[image: image description]

the bag file is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B30MDhMToXbPS0pIdHl4b1JRVEU) (/scan /odom)

my map is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B30MDhMToXbPQzFPT21EMnVxajQ)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256634/amcl:-cannot-match-well,-jumps-crazily.../) by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2017-03-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-03-11**:
Jumps are often caused by amcl, maybe run "rosrun tf tf_echo" on both transforms to see which transform is actually jumping.

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-03-11**:
@Humpelstilzchen I have make sure that its caused by amcl dismatch. I have uploaded a picture in my question. I dont know why amcl cannot match laser

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-03-12**:
Looks like you need some amcl tuning. This is a bit outside my expertise but setting odom_alpha1-4 in [amcl](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl) is a good start. (Also look at odom_model_type->diff-corrected when setting odom_alpha).

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-03-12**:
Also make sure [your odom works](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Troubleshooting)!

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-03-12**:
@Humpelstilzchen  Thank you! I tried but nothing changes. Could you please help me check? all my files have been uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will always get your sensor information in the sensor frame. Thus, you need to set up your robot correctly for doing localization.

I.e., you need to have a correct tf tree specifiying the robots transformations (where is the sensor w.r.t the `base_link`) and you need to publish the odometry to tf as well.

There are thorough descriptions in [the ROS navigation Tutorials about how to set up your robot correctly](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup#Robot_Setup)

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-03-10**:
My problem has been updated. Could you please have a look?